# Can you create a sub-collection from flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering if you could create a sub-collection from within flutter to firestore. I've heard you need to add manually add a document or something like that before you can access a sub-collection from flutter, but I wanted to know if there was a work-around.

Something like this-> Firebase.Firestore.instance.collection('groups').doc(groupID).collection('posts').add('')

without having to manually add a document first. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Firestore (all client platforms, not just Flutter), both collections and subcollections don't "exist" in the console unless there is at least one document in it.  If you want a subcollection to "exist", simply write a document to it.

When the last document is removed from a collection or subcollection, it ceases to "exist" in the console (after you reload it).

Collections are not really an "thing" in firestore.  Documents are a thing, and they happen to be organized under collections.  Your app should not depend on collections or subcollections existing - it should depends on documents being returned from queries on those collections.

See also:

- [Is possible to check if a collection or sub collection exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997748/is-possible-to-check-if-a-collection-or-sub-collection-exists)
- [How to check if Cloud Firestore collection exists? ( querysnapshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043320/how-to-check-if-cloud-firestore-collection-exists-querysnapshot)
- [In Dart/Flutter, how can I find out if there is no Collection in the Firestore database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055565/in-dart-flutter-how-can-i-find-out-if-there-is-no-collection-in-the-firestore-d)